# Изменение регистра строки JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Нужна небольшая помощь в JS, в котором я в принципе не силен. Имеется переменная со строкой вида "ivanovas", необходимо изменить регистр этой строки на такой "IvanovAS", как я понял в JS'e нет возможности менять регистр конкретного символа и можно это сделать только со всей строкой. Мой вариант решения это дергать из строки первый символ и последние два, менять у них регистр и потом лепить это в единое целое. Или может быть есть какие то более простые варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: Ваш вариант единственный и вполне работающий. Другие будут просто вариацией этого варианта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var a = 'ivanovas';
var b = a.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1, -2) + a.substr(-2).toUpperCase();
```